# Transform 3 rows into 3 columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I would like to melt 3 repeated rows into one rows with 3 columns:

```
> tail(days,12)
        Result       type count
412  Cancelled  D_(27,32]   122
413     Failed  D_(27,32] 11113
414 Successful  D_(27,32]   141
415  Cancelled  E_(27,32]   133
416     Failed  E_(27,32]  8266
417 Successful  E_(27,32]   104
418  Cancelled  F_(27,32]    92
419     Failed  F_(27,32]  7973
420 Successful  F_(27,32]    90
421  Cancelled HR_(27,32]   328
422     Failed HR_(27,32] 33697
423 Successful HR_(27,32]   298
```

I would like to have like this:

```
       type     Cancelled Failed Successful
    D_(27,32]   122       11113     141
```

I could use `apply`, but I'm sure there is something like `melt` which might solve my problem.

Comment: Not `melt`, but the opposite: `dcast`.

Comment: Just use `xtabs` from base R as in `xtabs(count ~  type + Result, days)`